# remove duplicate value but keep rest of the row values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a excel sheet(csv) like this one:

[image: Excel data]

and I want the output(tab delimited) to be like this:

[image: excel data 2]

Basically:

- replace duplicates with blanks but

  - if **col6** value is different from the previous row for the same
    **col1**
    value, all the data fields should be included.

I am struggling to create a formula which would do this. 
If I try to "Remove Duplicates" it removes the value and shifts the values up one row. I want it to remove the duplicates but not shift the values up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (note, you need a blank top row (edit: Actually, you're fine you have a header row)):

```
=IF(A2<>A1,A2,IF(D2<>D1,A2,""))
=IF(A2<>A1,B2,IF(D2<>D1,B2,""))
=IF(A2<>A1,C2,IF(D2<>D1,C2,""))
etc
```

in the top row and drag down

Edit: Noticed you needed an additional condition.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfect, with some minor improvements

Answer (score 8):

Given that duplicate data cells are next to each other

and data are on column A with blank top row, this should work. It will remove duplicates except the first occurrence.

```
=IF(A1=A2,"",A2)
=IF(A2=A3,"",A3)
.
.
.
```

Comment: this is better than selected solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
=IF((COUNTIF(A1:A$203,A1))=1,A1,"")
```

It  will count duplicates and for the last count it will keep value.

Try  `COUNTIF(A1:A$203,A1)` and you should be good to understand the logic.

Comment: Is there any other way to keep first occurrence of data and replace further occurrences with blank?

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a formula? I suppose you could do something like this. Although it might be easier to use a macro:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A6,"=" & A7),"",A7)
```

[image: Example1]

You could have a duplicate table on a separate tab using this formula to clear the rows you don't need - or however you want. Good Luck.

Comment: This doesnt take into consideration the second condition.

Comment: @stackErr Are you familiar with the AND() function in excel? You can add as many conditions as you want to that IF() statement. I recommend you learn it - it avoids nested IF() statements like in the answer you accepted.

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is what you are suggesting `=IF(AND($A2<>$A1,$F2<>$F1),F2,"")`. The logic does not make sense since it will check for both being true...while the logic in the accepted answer is more like `if(A2<>A1) elseif(D2<>D1) else`. structure.

Comment: @stackErr What about OR() - would that be any help to you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, created a macro for it, so it doesnt really matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that doesn't involve a helper column... conditional formatting.

Highlight A2:G(whatever the last cell is)

Use a formula to decide which cells to highlight

Formula would be `=AND($A2=$A1,$F2=$F1)`

Set the format to be white text (or equal to whatever you have the background color)